# Is « si jamais il venait à faire » more unlikely than « si jamais il en venait à faire »?

Tags: sens, usage

> 1) Si jamais il **venait à** tenter quoi que ce soit, on serait prévenues tout de suite !

= "If he should ever try anything funny, ..."

In the 1st example, the expression "venir à faire" serves to indicate a lower possibility of his unscrupulous actions than the version without it "si jamais il tentait ..." does.

> 2) Si jamais il **en venait à** tenter quoi que ce soit, on serait prévenues tout de suite !

= "If he ever came to try anything funny, ..."

In the 2nd example, on the other hand, the expression "en venir à faire" in the sense of "finir par faire" simply takes the form of Imparfait to describe a rather unlikely condition.

---

Q1. Given this, am I correct in assuming that the 1st is somewhat more unlikely than the 2nd?

Q2. You could never mix and match these two expressions and say "si jamais il **venait à en venir à** tenter ...", correct?

Comment: In English  I’d use the notions of “**he** ever **happening to**” & “**it** ever **coming to**,” respectively, for the 2 French constructions at issue (but in English at least, I don’t see one as being more likely to occur than the other) ie: 1) “Si jamais il venait à tenter”=”If **he** ever happens  to try something”..2) “Si jamais il en venait à tenter”=”If **it** ever comes to him/his trying something.” Mixing these two, in English at least, would, imo, decrease the likelihood (If it ever comes to him/his happening to try something) without it sounding quite as redundant as the combo in Q2.

Comment: Dans "en venait à faire", il y a l'idée d'une cause ("en"), parfois explicitée précédemment, mais très souvent implicite. Par exemple, "Les autres sorties sont trop dangereuses. Il faudra bien qu'il en vienne à passer par ici." ; "S'il était en colère, il pourrait en venir à le frapper.". Au contraire, quand on dit "s'il vient à faire..." on ne pense à aucune cause particulière qui pourrait pousser le sujet à agir ; on part du postulat qu'il agira pour une raison ou une autre, et on en tire les conséquences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"En", here, has the meaning of "from something (indicated before)".

It is a pronoun as defined [here (second tab EN²)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/en).

Examples:

> *"Il était à l'école. Il en sort à l'instant."* (il sort de l'école)
>
> *"Il a réfléchit. Il en a déduit la solution."* (il a déduit de sa réflexion)
>
> *"Ils se sont disputés. Si jamais ils en venaient à se battre, ce serait dramatique."* (à cause de cette dispute, s'ils venaient à se battre)

So both sentences (1/ and 2/) are correct but the meaning is a bit different as the second one uses "en" which is referring to something why/from "he comes to attempt...", and the first one refers to nothing particular but simply describes something that could happen.

Concerning Q2 *"si jamais il venait à en venir à tenter ..."*... is correct but surely the double usage of "venir" sounds not so good.

I'd prefer *"si jamais il lui arrivait d'en venir à tenter..."* or *"si jamais il arrivait qu'il en vienne à tenter..."* or something like that.

But the sentence is weird too because:

> "si jamais" => in case of
>
> "il venait" => it may happen
>
> "tenter" => attempt

so that sounds like few possibilities that it will ever occur, finally...

Answer (score 0):

Q1 : the only difference between the 2 sentences is *en*. The difference is the same as *if he comes to* and *if he ever comes to*.
Q2 : *s'il venait à en venir* can be heard. No strict grammatical problem. But *s'il en venait* is enough. Idem in english I I think : *if he comes to ever come to try...*
Attention cependant on dit toujours *s'il en venait aux mains* mais celà sort de votre question puisque *aux mains* n'est pas un verbe.

Comment: I don't think that is the difference in English.  |If he comes to ever come to try| is not idiomatic. Idiomatic would be: If he ***ever came to try to*** [do something] or If ***he were ever to try*** [x] Et puis: si jamais il venait à en venir à tenter me semble pléonastique.